# Clive Ke’s wrong?

Tags: analysis

As you see, Clive suggests moving the knight, but how on earth can black get a pawn to a3?

> [image: Nothing in a3??!!]

Comment: The second image shows the pawn has been moved from H7 to H6. It's surely a typo, as none of the black pawns could move to A3.

Comment: "As you see" ... or not as not everyone can see in the same way.  You should always transcribe text in images.

Answer (score 8):

It's probably a typo. Perhaps he meant ...h6

Comment: Comparing the first image with the second image, it's evident the pawn has been moved from H7 to H6. It's not probably a typo: It's a typo.

Comment: Specifically, a board rotation-typo (a3 from White is h6 from Black), which is a quite common goof that even might happen to me once a year.